# Some links broken after Update of Wordpress Multidomain Site

Tags: wordpress, domain-mapping

I have build a Wordpress site which is running on multiple (sub-)domains using the Plugin: **WordPress MU Domain Mapping**.

I have been out of WP-Development but had to update those sites. On the main site everything went great. After a few seconds, the site was updated.

The 3 mapped sites however are having a few problems.

After digging into the code i figured that no CSS or JS is being loaded anymore (404 Not Found)?

I can't seem to find the problem that causes this. What has changed so drastic that all those links are being thrown off?

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?
I'm happy to provide functions.php, header.php or anything else that could help to locate the problem.

Comment: The weird part is that some scripts can be found. 
For example: all JS-Plugins are throwing a 404, the scripts.js is loading just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was WordPress MU Domain Mapping.

Although at some points it was deactivated it still set the primary domains and caused funny redirects.

Got all pages running in directories now and just need to solve the mapping to sub-domains without the plugin (which should be a core-feature) since 4.5